# Median spaces as retracts of hypercubes

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry

It is known ([See e.g. here, Theorem 2.1](http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~victor.chepoi/survey_cm_bis.pdf)) that median graphs are retracts of hypercubes.

**Question**: Is it also known that median metric spaces are retract of some $l¹$ product of unit intervals?

By retract, I mean the existence of a $1$-Lipschitz self-map restricting to the identity on its image.

**Edit:** After some discussion, an easy counter-example is actually $Y:=\{0,1\}$ (distance 1) (shame on me): If $Y$ were embedded in some "full" hypercube $C$ in some retractable way, any point $x \in C$ between $0$ and $1$  would have to still be between $0$ and $1$ after retraction, (while not increasing its distance to either), which cannot happen.

Thus, an ammended version of the question would be:

**New question:** Is it known that median spaces are retract of some $l¹$ product of *subspaces of* closed compact real intervals?

Comment: About the amended question: what do you think of $[0,1]^2-\{(0,0)\}$ with $\ell^1$-product on the square?

Comment: This one seems hard to embed in a retractable way, but maybe in some very large product space…